# Chefs and Technologists are the most powerful people. Why is this?

Tags: society

In my world:

Chefs can make excellent food, unparalleled in the universe.
(or at least one can) (the bestselling dish is tomato mushroom soup)

Technologists can do almost anything, but are *very* lazy.
(reason - the best one is a baby. He invents things by accident, such as making a teleportation device to steal the aforementioned tomato mushroom soup)

The problem I'm facing is that they are supposed to be the most powerful people in my world. However, given their usability or temperaments, it does not seem likely that they should be.

### Background

This is an *very* weird world. (mostly invented by my very little brother)

- formed from alive-potion induced potato (don't ask)
- tech can do anything, pretty much (only *slightly* breaking the energy conservation laws)
- They are crazy for food, however they might have an overabundance of chefs.
- The chief Chef is reclusive
- Technologists are way too focused on coding projects.
- They are the dominant race, throughout the universe.
- the chef doesn't make stuff for no reason; its only purpose is to taste good.
- Also cancer suppression etc. is widespread.
- They are not an grabby (want more planets) species, Pluto (w/ extra 4th dimension added space) is enough.
- They have a population of above 3 quadrillion.
- Pure democracy
- Everything political/science/kinship etc is friendly
- the species as a whole are very kind, unless something harms them.
- The chef and technologist are sister/brother
- The technology is restricted by an rsa-4398046511104 (quantum-encryption confirmation) passcard needed; not having one causes tech to self destruct in an completely-destroyed-nonrecoverable manner. (They *do* let others use the tech, however with pressures not to break the codes of conduct and violate thus disabling their passcards. Also the chef can refuse to cook for people chef deems bad.)
- The food is only possible to be made by the chef. His techniques are so exotic even using an ultra-clear super slo-mo camera could not record the chef's methods.
- And, this world has a different hierarchal system than humans. They respect Knowledge and Craft beyond power - it's insignificant to them. (However, the above question still holds as they are lazy. And reclusive.)
- The chef owns the restaurant, the tech person owns the entire Technology branch.
  -The chefs and technologists are tiered, with more at the bottom and one chef and one technologist at the top. However the two at the top are lazy and reclusive.
- They stayed hidden for very long; and because of their way of life: pushing the limits of science, have created technology far beyond what anyone else in the universe is capable of rivaling, thus the influence they have.

(As for frame challenges, it would be great if it doesn't break the fact that they are supposed to be the most powerful people in the world)

### TL;DR

The chef and the tech person at the top (leaders) are reclusive and lazy. They are also the most powerful people. This does not make sense. It would be great if a specific scenario can make this make sense.

Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just asking, is an TL;DR not enough?

Comment: Oops. That's a bot.

Comment: If they don't let anyone else use their technology, and they are restricted to a single planet, and they don't care about politics, why would they be at the top? They have no influence on outsiders.

Comment: They *do* let others use the tech, however with pressures not to break the codes of conduct and violate thus disabling their passcards. Also the chef can refuse to cook for people chef deems bad.

Comment: They stayed hidden for very long; and because of their way of life pushing the limits of science have created technology far beyond what anyone else in the universe is capable of rivaling.

Comment: Also they like to eat, so their food is also at the pinnacle of yummy.

Comment: The question is also about their own society's functions, and not political connections throughout the galaxy.

Comment: Can answers invoke magic as the reason?

Comment: FWIW - RSA-256 is _weak_ by modern standards.  RSA-256"MB" is meaningless, as that suffix is used for bytes rather than bitwidth.

Comment: @jdunlop Oops. Forgot to catch up on Cryptography for a while - I mean the private keys are around 256 megabytes long each. (Also I see why encryption wouldn't work here. Hmm. Wait - what if the system was like SSL where there needs to be a certificate for the passcards, and as the top level domain, the technologist could just invalidate someone's certificate?)

Comment: @Michael Hall Yes, answers can invoke magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Give silly reasons

Your setting is meant to be humorous, so you should just give silly non-explanations. The President begs the Chef for his approval for a new public works project, and the Chef agrees only on condition that it include a hundred new ketchup factories (the Chef misplaced his ketchup recently, you see, and is quite concerned this shortage of ketchup should not happen again). The President asks the Chef how come the Chef is in charge and not the President, and for answer the Chef hands him a cress sandwich. The President's eyes roll back in his head as he devours it. The Chef then asks the President to make *him* a cress sandwich, and the cressfallen President admits that he cannot. He never studied the art, you see. "And that's why I'm in charge," says the Chef, patting the President gently on the head.

Some other reasons:

- "Chef" sounds a lot like "Chief," doesn't it? Mmm-hmm.
- An army marches on its stomach
- The workers are striking without their lunchtime hors d'ouvres . Please, Chef, have mercy on us!
- Weaponized fruitcake
- "Behold, a man!" said Diogenes before Plato's Academy, holding a plucked chicken, a featherless biped. Everyone begrudgingly agreed that it was a man, and who has more power over a plucked chicken than the Chef? That was when the Chef-ocracy began.
- "Life is like a kitchen. It's all a matter of knowing where your tomatoes are." The Chef could tap his nose and use a line like this to gloat over a captured political opponent. Captured by the Chef's death-squads, of course. Obviously the Chef has death-squads, though he tries not to let them distract too much from his cooking.

The technologist's source of power is even easier to explain. After all, he creates wondrous things for any situation that troubles him. Maybe he sells some of them, maybe he puts in backdoors to what he sells.

Comment: And this is something closer to what I wanted! Thanks! (still waiting a bit to accept for more people) Have a nice day!

Comment: It would be nice if the technologist had a big brother who does marketing.

Comment: "Chef" is indeed German for Head/Chief/Boss/Manager if you want to play with that connection.

Answer (score 3):

### Frame challenge

> *There's two kinds of people, my friend: those with loaded guns and those who dig. You dig.* (Spoken by the character Blondie in Sergio Leone's 1966 film [*The Good, the Bad and the Ugly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly).)

The big problem with the premise of the question is that cooks and engineers, even if they take the fancy job titles of chefs and technologists, are execution roles. People in execution roles are never the most powerful; most usually they are not powerful at all. They take orders; they don't give orders. They make stuff or do stuff; they don't decide what stuff to make or do.

A restaurant has many cooks but only one boss. The boss can fire the cooks, but the cooks cannot fire the boss. A company has many engineers, sometimes even in the tens of thousands, but only one Chief Executive Officer; the CEO can fire any engineer, and sometimes many engineers at once, but the engineers cannot fire the CEO.

Power belongs to the people who can decide what cooks works for them and what cooks don't; who can decide whether the cook will make tomato mushroom soup (yuck) or eggs Benedict (good). The cook does not get to decide what dishes they will make; the restaurant's manager decides. Maybe the cook can make the world's best tomato mushroom soup (yuck): but it is not for the cook to decide whether the restaurant offers tomato mushroom soup (yuck) or not.

Comment: And, this world has a different hierarchal system than humans. They respect Knowledge and Craft beyond power - it's insignificant to them.

Comment: However, the above question still holds as they are lazy. And reclusive.

Comment: Also, they are Head Chef, and Head Technologist. They do give orders. Somewhat.

Comment: > As for frame challenges, it would be great if it doesn't break the fact that they are supposed to be the most powerful people in the world < As this idea is central to the story, I'm sorry this may not be what I'm looking for... Thanks for your effort and great answer, though!

Comment: The chef owns the restaurant, the tech person owns the entire Technology branch.

Comment: @MichaelChen: The question does not ask about **a** chef and **a** technologist being the two most powerful people in the world. The question is about chef**s** and technologist**s** being the most powerful people in the world; which cannot be, because chefs and technologists are many. The joke about many chiefs and no indians comes to mind. At work we have tens of thousands of engineers; we engineers are by far a majority of the workforce: over whom are we supposed to have power?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add: The chefs and technologists are teired, with more at the bottom and one chef and one technologists at the top. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To solve the indians with no cheif; the head chef and head technologist act as leaders; however they are a bit lazy and reclusive; the question proposes a solution where their rule and command have effect even considering their more reclusive traits.

Comment: Sorry for my bad wording in my question; I edited it for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelChen, your steam of justifying comments seems to pretty much answer the question.  Just make it so…

Answer (score 1):

## The illuminati has made it so

A secret cabal of kazziliononaires and galactic influencers has recognized the extreme value of the two figures- they are beings of godlike power who could change the fate of the universe. As such, they arrange things behind the scene so that the two can do whatever they want.

Suppose the chef makes an amazing dish of tomato soup which can cure cancer. This is worth several planets. The technologist then invents a teleporter. This is worth several star clusters. The illuminati will arrange for interesting settings and backlogs for the two to fight so that they can steal the prototypes or the failed dishes and sell them for an absolutely obscene amount.

Anything the two want will be provided for them, because their inventions are just so valuable everyone needs them.

Comment: Sorry: They are the dominant race. Throughout the universe.

Comment: Added to background. Also, the chef doesn't make stuff for no reason; it's only purpose is to taste good. Also cancer suppression etc. is widespread.

Comment: They are brothers and sisters.

Comment: I edited it to account for that. Perhaps the reason cancer suppression is so common is because a chance dish the chef made by chance did that and they copied that and made bank. They're just so absurdly good that the powers that be give them whatever they want so they can get more.

Comment: > They are the dominant race. < They care not to be manipulated.

Comment: I've edited the question body with more context. Hope it helps!